# Paper.js Mouseup Event Inhibited by Tool

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mouseevent, paperjs

I'm using Paper.js and I need to do something on `mouseup` on a raster. However the event does not seem to fire when I use the global tool space.

Note this [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/nZI9T8MwEIb/yslLG6mN9yAmGEFCRUyYwaTXxE1zZ9mXZKj637GTwgQd8Pbex3Ovzz4rsj2qSr12KHWrNqrmfdZaw0NAKwgWgo2CAZxgD0N01IC0CG+7J0OjDd/peyCcYDeLtVGtiK+09tZjOMaSQ6NlEA7OnqJ2vW0w6olDl3DbyUm7XTBR90y2PPrGqOLOkKHk5JlHnGdeRwnPqkbKig+zGh1OhpaK0nN04piSqxwvl9KZly1HsUEeg21e2JHM4Wsj03rV8xBxzxOtNnAYqM6gNY4JUcDZEKRTM0U+YXniJt31auunL1sHQ5fid3Ka+y9y6rtNHvzf3JvowS/bTtz0BT7Tw3c+byaq6v3j8gU=), where clicking and dragging yields a log something like this:

> raster mousedown
>
> raster mousedrag
>
> ... [more "raster mousedrag"] ...
>
> raster mousedrag
>
> raster mouseup

indicating the `raster.on('mouseup' function() {...});` was hit properly, as expected.

However, in this [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/nVM9b9tADP0rhBbLgCOhq4pOydiggY2iQ9XhItHSxRIp3FHWEPi/l3eyk1hNMvQ2fj0+ku+eEzI9JkWyO6BUbbJJKq6Dnedw69AIggFnvKADK9jD6C01IC3Cz+33ko7GXcLfgHCCbTTSMmlFhiLPBzOge/IZuyaXUdhZ0/nc9qZBn0/sDgp3M1lpb2YYn/dMJnsamjJZfy2pJGVyz0eMPc+thKNVIQWL99E6WpxKmjOygb0Vy6Ssgj+bUyNeoOzFOLlzpnlgSxLd+5GqWMF0z6PHO54oxaPWreG5JNB3XaXQMay9ZozT+ziav8AJL7Joedphh9WZadjfg5E226rLUNNh+qYivL3jvljw2FynCBdveS2iXhwf8JY7dgWsHNardxN+2VraAr68xk7zMS6mHmUnPMQRLoLwcRSswahwdHyolSKkYSomBOuhioqq12CohnGAR6yMrggmVCpQa9Zrh6vlZA571cAPWi4ktChA3IiLOcZhdi8mmG/0IhOmdNWHK9V67dUGLsdbHKxi8txh1nGjyj6L8KUuCBUUet7QP8jK8L+Qte5z5HH4GPdT6HGY/5bi6od/1KMcolZ8Uvz+c/oL), which contains functionality for displaying the dragged area, the `raster.on('mouseup' function() {...});` is not hit properly. Note that the log does not contain "raster mouseup", only "raster mousedown" and "raster mousedrag".

Why in the second instance does `mouseup` not fire on the raster? How can I adjust the code in the second sketch so that it does fire?

Comment: I ended up opening an issue on github because of a problem I saw when playing with this - if you use view.on('drag', ...) then the rectangle's .removeOn function is not called. Mouse handling in paper could probably use a bit of an overhaul. I typically use only two types of handlers - a global tool handler and then, if needed, specific handlers for path.removeOn(...) if needed.

Comment: This is going to be fixed in paperjs but Júrg provided a clean workaround: set the red rectangle to be a guide. See the sketch in his comment here: https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/842#issuecomment-166155595

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simple answer is that the problem is that the `on('mouseup', ...)` handler is never called. The paper code gets the most recent hit, i.e., the red rectangle you're drawing, and checks to see if that responds to the 'mouseup' event. It doesn't. Then it checks the parent chain and the parent of the red rectangle is the layer, so it doesn't pass the `.responds` test either. Because the raster is at the same level as the red rectangle handlers associated with the raster are never called.

The simplest answer is to install the handlers on the `view`, not the `raster`, by using the global tool, e.g.,

```
function onMouseUp(event) {
    console.log('vup');
}
```

See the paperjs code (in [CanvasView.js](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/blob/develop/src/view/CanvasView.js)):

```
function callEvent(view, type, event, point, target, lastPoint) {
    var item = target,
        mouseEvent;

    function call(obj) {
        if (obj.responds(type)) {
            if (!mouseEvent) {
                mouseEvent = new MouseEvent(type, event, point, target,
                        lastPoint ? point.subtract(lastPoint) : null);
            }
            if (obj.emit(type, mouseEvent) && mouseEvent.isStopped) {
                event.preventDefault();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    while (item) {
        if (call(item))
            return true;
        item = item.getParent();
    }
    if (call(view))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```